# Why is the Hover effect working without placing the mouse over the hover text?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, dropdown

I created a dropdown menu. Here, **my problem is in the **portfolio** section**. When I hover on portfolio, a dropdown menu comes. Then when I hover on the first dropdown menu text then  another sub-dropdown menu should be come but here all sub-dropdown menu of other dropdown menu has come one by one.

Another problem is in the **Contact section**. Here, the problem is if I use a small bottom-margin between each dropdown menu, then after hover on the Contact text ,the dropdown icon comes and when I move the mouse from the text to dropdown icon, the dropdown menu went away.

Here is my full code:

```css
/* menu part */

.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #545454;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 55px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li i {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 49, 49);
  transition: .8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* dropdown menu part */


/* contact part */

.menu ul li .contact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li .contact li {
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
}

.menu ul li .contact li i {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 25px;
}

.menu ul li .contact li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: rgb(190, 201, 37);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 22, 22);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: rgb(1, 130, 250);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:last-child:hover {
  background-color: rgb(66, 110, 241);
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* portfolio part */

.menu ul li .portfolio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li {
  width: 84px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li ul li {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li:hover ul li {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: .8s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dropdown menu.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-female"></i>About</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>Contact
        <ul class="contact">
          <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-wordpress-simple"></i>Portfolio
        <ul class="portfolio">
          <li>Work no 1
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 2
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 3
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 4
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 5
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Login</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need also to switch the display from none to block, else it is unseen but still stretch the parent which leaves a blank area that reacts to hover.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not use the classic display:none/block , your hidden elements are here using space that is part of the parent. When you hover those spaces, you hover the parent .. :hover is applied.

To avoid `display:none`/`block;` you may use `pointer-events:none`/`auto;` instead on the ul child.

here is an example of your code.

```css
/* menu part */

.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #545454;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 55px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li i {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 49, 49);
  transition: .8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* dropdown menu part */


/* contact part */

.menu ul li .contact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38px;
  top: 100%;
   
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li .contact li {
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0) translate(-1em);
  transform-origin: top;
  }
  .menu ul li .contact li ul {
  /* added */ pointer-events: none;  
}

.menu ul li .contact li i {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 25px;
}

.menu ul li .contact li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: rgb(190, 201, 37);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 22, 22);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: rgb(1, 130, 250);
}

.menu ul li .contact li:last-child:hover {
  background-color: rgb(66, 110, 241);
}

.menu ul li:hover .contact  li {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scaleY(1) translate(-1em);
  cursor: pointer;
  }

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  /* added */ pointer-events: auto;
 
}


/* portfolio part */

.menu ul li .portfolio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li {
  width: 84px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  /* added */ pointer-events: none;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li ul li {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.menu ul li .portfolio li:hover ul li {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: .8s;
  /* added */ pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dropdown menu.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-female"></i>About</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>Contact
        <ul class="contact">
          <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-wordpress-simple"></i>Portfolio
        <ul class="portfolio">
          <li>Work no 1
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 2
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 3
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 4
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Work no 5
            <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Login</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```